# How much bandwidth is needed to synchronize Ethereum in fast sync mode?

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereum-wallet-dapp, geth-clique

I want to deploy an Ethereum client to become a full node. According to the hardware recommendation on the [official website](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/nodes-and-clients/) , I need CPU with 4 cores, 16GB of RAM, 500GB of SSD and 25MB/s of bandwidth. I can configure CPU, memory, hard disk as recommended, but 25GB/s of bandwidth is a hassle for me, and 8GB/s is a bit out of my range. Therefore, I would like to ask, is such a large bandwidth necessary to synchronize an Ethereum client? How much bandwidth does your GETH need to synchronize and how many nodes are connected? Thanks very much！！！！！！！！！！！！

Comment: Is bandwidth directly related to the maximum number of connected nodes?

Answer (score 2):

[It says](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/nodes-and-clients/#recommended-specifications) "25+ MBit/s bandwidth".

This is 3.125 MB/s, which is 0.003125 GB/s.

The actual bottleneck will be applying all the state updates to your local data, and writing them to SSD.

Comment: thanks for sharing your inputs here. Sorry for reaching you out of the blue. I was wondering if you could assist me with this. I am kind of not finding any information anywhere else.
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/118130/swap-for-tokens-with-bot-protection-enabled-bpenabled
Thanks a ton in advance.

Comment: Hi @AmithKumar - interesting question :-) I haven't looked at the PancakeSwap contract code for a while, and their front-end code isn't publicly available, so it's not possible to know how it handles errors passed back to it. At the risk of suggesting something too simplistic, have you checked the console logs for the page when the error gets returned? (I know you're using your phone - might be easier to check on a laptop with the developer console open.) It might be that the actual error gets console logged before the generic error is output to the UI.

Comment: Actually, that's a great idea. I don't know why I didn't think of it :). I will check & see if I can find something there. Thanks again for your promptly responding.